# Should I avoid using the annotation @Transactional when the transaction only reads data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I've migrated from old style of transaction management with `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` to a Declarative transaction management recommended by Spring to avoid exceptions with transactions that appear from time to time.

For transactions `save` `update` `delete` I added the annotation:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)`

It works good for me.

The question is:

> Should I avoid using the annotation `@Transactional` when the transaction only reads data?

*Example:*

```
public TradeData getTrade(long tradeId) throws Exception {
   return em.find(TradeData.class, tradeId);
}
```

After reading [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html) article, which says:

> "Better yet, just avoid using the `@Transactional` annotation altogether when doing read operations, as shown in Listing 10:"

I'm a little confused and I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For read-only operations with `JDBC` you don't need the `@Transactional` because it doesn't need a transaction, `Hibernate` does! So you can use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`. Then you are sure you don't update, delete, insert something by accident.

Answer (score 5):

If a particular method of your service just read information from the database yes, you can put it as read-only

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Object yourReadOnlyMethod(){}
```